Pricipal bundle map is homeomorphism on fibers
This is the same question as Principal bundle map is fiber homeomorphism. But since I don't have 50 reputation to comment on one of the answers, I made this new question.
I want to prove that if $q:E \rightarrow X$ and $q':E' \rightarrow X'$ are principal $G$-bundles and $f:E \rightarrow E'$ is a bundle map, meaning
$$f(p \cdot g) = f(p)g$$
for every $p \in E$ and $g \in G$, then $f$ induces homeomorphisms between the fibers $E_p \rightarrow E'_{f(p)}$.
My idea was the same as in this answer. You trivialise around $p$ and $f(p)$, and use the trivialisations to identify the fibers with $G$. More specifically: Take a trivialisation $(U,\Phi)$ of $E$ around $p$ and a trivialisation $(V,\Psi)$ of $E'$ around $f(p)$. We have $\Phi=(q,\phi)$ and $\Psi=(q',\psi)$. We can identify $E_p$ with $G$ using $\phi$, and we can identify $E'_{f(p)}$ with $G$ using $\psi$. To show that $f$ is a homeomorphism on the fibers, we look at the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
E_p @>{f}>> E'_{f(p)} \\
@V{\phi}VV @V{\psi}VV \\
G@>{h}>> G
\end{CD}$$
If we can show that $h$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ will be a homeomorphism on the fibers.
My question: What is $h$? I am unable to find it. The aforementioned answer claims that $h=id_G$, but I think this is false (For a counterexample, take $E=E'$, $f=id_E$ and two different trivialisations).
If anyone has another method of proving this, that would also be appreciated.
Thanks.

$h$ is the left multiplication by some fixed element of $G$ (namely, $h(1)$).

Yeah now I see it. Thanks!
